# pass parameter to taskkill() in matlab?

Tags: matlab, system, pid, taskkill

Suppos there are many matlab.exe running on a windows PC, I am trying to terminate all of them, except the one I am working on. I did the following:

```
curPID = feature('getpid')
%say curPID return 10000.
%then follow:
system('taskkill /F /FI "PID ne 10000" /IM matlab.EXE');
%the above works fine.
```

But since every time, when I run

```
curPID = feature('getpid')
```

in different matlab GUI or m-file, the value of curPID will change, so I tried to pass curPID to the system() function as below:

```
system('taskkill /F /FI "PID ne curPID"/IM matlab.EXE');
% or
system('taskkill /F /FI "PID ne str2num(curPID)"/IM matlab.EXE');
```

but they do not work.

How can I pass curPID to taskkill?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to format your call to [`sys`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sys.html):

```
curPID = feature('getpid');
syscall = sprintf('taskkill /F /FI "PID ne %u" /IM matlab.EXE', curPID);
system(syscall);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. By the way, what is the equivalent on a Linux cluster?

Comment: @XAM I don't know. Probably a better question for SuperUser, not SO.